# How can I use "uniq -c" command of unix in python code?

Tags: python, unix

I have to check how many times each word occurs in a paragraph. I have to print the word along with the number of occurence.

For example, If the paragraph is

> > how are you now? Are you better now?

then the output should be:

> > how-1 
> >  
> >     are-2 
> >  
> >     you-2 
> >  
> >     now-2 
> >  
> >     better-1

I tried using the subprocess

> > from subprocess import call 
> >     sen=raw_input("enter:")
> >     call(["uniq", "-c",sen])

but the function wants a file as input. I dont want to input a file. How do I make it work.

Comment: Why don't you just code it in Python?

Comment: am not aware of the string handling functions in python. It will be difficult for me. I thought it would be easy if I get the unix command working inside python script

Comment: I got it working. Thanks guys.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/28766796/… this link helped me. But it's not the way i wanted it. I still want to know how to use the unix command in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for completeness, this is how you could solve it in Python:

```
import re, collections

paragraph = "how are you now? Are you better now?"

splitter = re.compile('\W')
counts = collections.Counter(word.lower() 
                             for word in splitter.split(paragraph) 
                             if word)
for word, count in counts.most_common():
    print(count, word)
```

Comment: Bravo for adding it, but this is nearly a copy from the link OP provided saying that something helped him up there.

Comment: I feel like it's different enough that I'll keep this here. None of the solutions to that answer used `Counter.most_common` or split on correct word boundaries.

Comment: Use of Counter() was shown there, but I didn't tell you to remove the A, hey it's good that it's here.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon this does work. I can understand that re.compile() function, splits words when it sees a white space. Then I understand that every word is probably changed into lower case and that the counter helps in keeping a record of the words. The 1st for loop is to traverse through each word in the para. But I cant understand why we are checking for length of word to be > 0 and most_common() fnction. Can you please explain that part. I understand the other loop is to print the unique words with the help of counts which we obtained using counter. I hope I have understood. Please correct m

Comment: @charvi you are right. The if is because the split will return empty strings for the punctuation. I could probably have left out the length check because of how Python handles falsy values. The most_common just sorts by count, descending.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon How and where is each unique word stored and matched in this code. Is the collections.counter having some buffer objects to hold the words as they are read from the paragraph?

Comment: Yes. Counter is basically a specialised dictionary-like object. Similar to an awk array. It will maintain keys for each word.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment to [Dimitris Jim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4952130/dimitris-jim) (I'd post as comment but not enough rep), you'll also need to sort the input. You can do this in python by replacing the regex statement with this

```
sen_list = sen.split(" ")
sen_list.sort()
sen = '\n'.join(sen_list)
```

I'm sure there's a way to do this with linux `sort`. Similarly, you can use `tr ' ' '\n'` to do the replacement of space with new line not in python.

Comment: Why on Earth would you sort the input before passing it to uniq? It doesn't change anything except the order in which the output is presented. Just loss of time. It makes more sense to sort the output, then you can sort it either alphabetically or by word count.

Comment: You absolutely have to sort the input to get the kind of answer OP is looking for, as `uniq` only merges consecutive duplicates. as mentioned in another answer.

Comment: Woops, I am sorry, I made a mistake. Therefore my answer was incomplete too. So I edited it to match suggestion in your A. I realized my mistake when I went testing my code on Linux because OP said that it doesn't work. I was distracted while answering and simply missed the complete uniq behavior. Sorry again!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to know how to do counting using uniq, then:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

sen = raw_input("Enter: ")
sen = sen.lower().split() # Remove capitals and split into list of words
# Sort list to provide correct count ("-c" option counts only consecutive repeats)
# If you want to get consecutives, just don't sort.
sen.sort()
sen = "\n".join(sen) # Put each word into its own line (for input)
# uniq accepts input from stdin
p = Popen(["uniq", "-c"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
out = p.communicate(sen)[0].split("\n") # Pass the input, and get the output (make it a list by splittin on newlines)
counts = [] # Parse output and put it into a list
for x in out:
    if not x: continue # Skip empty lines (usually appears at the end of output string)
    counts.append(tuple(x.split())) # Split the line into tuple(number, word) and add it to counts list

# And if you want a nice output like you presented in Q:
for x in counts:
    print x[1]+"-"+x[0]
```

Note1: This is definitely not a way of doing this. You really should code it in Python.

Note2: This is tested on cygwin and Ubuntu 12.04 with same results

Note3: uniq is not a function, it is a command i.e. a program stored in /bin/uniq and /usr/bin/uniq

Comment: @Charvi: Unfortunately, it works! Output was incorrect without sorting, I didn't really knew how uniq works. I went testing the code on Ubuntu (it works) and discovered that if you want complete count for each word, using uniq -c, then sorting is needed. Why doesn't it work for you?